# How to assign a network-unique name to the Public folder inside my home folder when viewed remotely

Tags: macos, network, finder, sharing

I have multiple Macs, all running El Capitain, and my login username on all of them is "Anon". When I have the Public folder from one machine mounted across a network on a different machine, that folder displays as "Anon's Public Folder".

That gets confusing if I have three or more computers on the same network (which I often do.) What I'd like is that if, for example, I have computers "Moe", "Larry", and "Curly" running, then a public folder from another machine would display as, for example, "Anon's Public Folder on Moe", or "Anon's Public Folder on Larry", as appropriate.

- I seem to have no control over the name of a Public folder
- I would like to be able to identify the host machine at a glance when I see a shared folder
- It would be nice if Public folders displayed both their user name and host name

Is there any way, either by setting System preferences or Finder preferences, or some other method, that I could achieve this goal? Even if I had to assign aliases to network-mounted folders manually.

For now, I keep a unique file in each, with a name like "0-Moe.txt", "0-Larry.txt", etc. The "0-" prefix is so it will sort at the top of the window in a view-by-name. But that's *so* hokey. I'd like something a little more elegant.